# JavaScript long form of shorthand code lacking braces

Tags: javascript

I'm looking through RosettaCode solutions for a particular [problem](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Abundant,_deficient_and_perfect_number_classifications#JavaScript):

```
for (var dpa=[1,0,0], n=2; n<=20000; n+=1) {
    for (var ds=1, d=2, e=Math.sqrt(n); d<e; d+=1) if (n%d==0) ds+=d+n/d
    if (n%e==0) ds+=e
    dpa[ds<n ? 0 : ds==n ? 1 : 2]+=1
}
```

And I've been trying to expand it into long form with brackets and spaces:

```
const dpa = [1, 0, 0];
let ds = 1;
for (let n = 2; n <= 20000; n += 1) {
  const e = Math.sqrt(n);
  for (let d = 2; d < e; d += 1) {
    if (n % d === 0) {
      ds += d + (n / d);
    }
  }
  if (n % e === 0) {
    ds += e;
  }
  dpa[ds < n ? 0 : ds === n ? 1 : 2] += 1;
}
```

Problem is, I'm getting different results, meaning I'm not rewriting it properly.

The result should be `[15043, 4, 4953]`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @luisenrike It's the second line. Though it should be inside the outer loop. Putting it inside the "inner for" would result in the last reference being `undefined`.

Comment: Oh god. I misplaced the `let ds = 1;` Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are taking some liberties in your translation, you are changing variables to constants and changing function scope to block scope. The true expansion of the original (implementing hoisting and not adding `const` or `let`) would be this:

```js
// Original 
(function original(){

  for (var dpa=[1,0,0], n=2; n<=20000; n+=1) {

    for (var ds=1, d=2, e=Math.sqrt(n); d<e; d+=1) if (n%d==0) ds+=d+n/d
    
    if (n%e==0) ds+=e
    dpa[ds<n ? 0 : ds==n ? 1 : 2]+=1
  }
  
  console.log(dpa);
}());

// Expanded
(function expanded(){
  var dpa; 
  var n;
  var ds; 
  var d; 
  var e; 
    
  for (dpa = [1,0,0], n = 2; n <= 20000; n += 1) {
    
    for (ds = 1, d = 2, e = Math.sqrt(n); d < e; d += 1){
      if (n % d == 0){ 
        ds += d + n / d;
      }
    }
    
    if (n % e == 0){ 
      ds += e;
    }
    
    dpa[ds < n ? 0 : ds == n ? 1 : 2] += 1; 
  }

  console.log(dpa);
}());
```

Comment: This would indeed be the ES5 answer. I should have specified that I was looking expansion and ES6, but I solved my own problem by simply moving the `let ds = 1` inside the first `for` loop. Thanks for your input.